# What is the best solution to add/delete a many-to-one mapped object with hibernate and struts

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Ticket class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tickets")
public class Ticket implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="requester_name")
private String requesterName;

@ManyToOne
private BusinessPurpose business_purpose;


@ManyToOne
private Park park;

@Column(name="no_of_tickets")
private Integer noOfTickets;


@ManyToOne
private Status status; 


@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

This is the part of jsp where i am allowing the user to enter details for new ticket. This jsp gets its data through ticketDTO object having all the fields defined in it.

```
function submitRegistration()
{
    var bpl = document.getElementById("bpl");
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].businessPurpose.value = bpl.options[bpl.selectedIndex].text;
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].park.value = document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].parkName.options[document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].parkName.selectedIndex].text;
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].stateName.value = document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].stateId.options[document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].stateId.selectedIndex].text;
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].countryName.value = document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].countryId.options[document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].countryId.selectedIndex].text;

    return isValid();
}

<s:form id="ticketRequestForm" method="post"
            action="submitTicket" theme="simple"
            onsubmit="return submitRegistration();">
            <s:hidden name="businessPurpose" />
            <s:hidden name="park" />

                    <td id="formtxt" width="20%">Requestor's Name</td>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <p class="form">
                            <s:textfield name="requesterName">
                            </s:textfield>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="formtxt" width="15%">Business Purpose</td>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <p class="form">
                            <s:select id="bpl" list="businessPurposeList"
                                name="businessPurposeId" listKey="id"
                                listValue="businessPurposeName" onchange="businessList();"></s:select>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                    <td id="formtxt" width="15%">Which Park</td>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <p class="form">
                            <s:select list="parkList" name="parkId" listKey="id"
                                listValue="name"></s:select>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </s:form>
```

P.S.: This is a stripped down version from a working jsp. Please mind some missing tags as i was trying to keep the post short. My main focus is on the list getting populated by objects inside objects.

**Now my first question here is - can i somehow use one jsp for both save and edit operations ??** I can get the complete details under one ticket object.

But for now i have implemented another jsp for editing. This jsp file gets its values through a ticket object populated in action class.

```
function submitRegistration()
{
    var bpl = document.getElementById("bpl");
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].businessPurpose.value = bpl.options[bpl.selectedIndex].text;
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].park.value = document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].parkName.options[document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].parkName.selectedIndex].text;
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].stateName.value = document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].stateId.options[document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].stateId.selectedIndex].text;
    document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].countryName.value = document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].countryId.options[document.forms['ticketRequestForm'].countryId.selectedIndex].text;

    return isValid();
}

<s:form id="ticketRequestForm" method="post"
            action="editTicket" theme="simple"
            onsubmit="return submitRegistration();">
            <s:hidden name="businessPurpose" />
            <s:hidden name="park" />
            <s:hidden name="stateName" />
            <s:hidden name="countryName" />

                <tr>
                    <td id="formtxt" width="20%">Requestor's Name</td>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <p class="form">
                            <s:textfield name="%{ticket.requesterName}" value="%{ticket.requesterName}">
                            </s:textfield>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="formtxt" width="15%">Business Purpose</td>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <p class="form">
                            <s:select id="bpl" list="businessPurposeList"
                                name="%{ticket.businessPurpose.businessPurposeId}" listKey="id"
                                listValue="%{ticket.businessPurpose.businessPurposeName}" onchange="businessList();"></s:select>
                        </p>
                    </td>

                    <td id="formtxt">Country</td>
                    <td valign="middle">
                        <p class="form">
                            <s:select list="countriesList" name="ticket.country.countryId" listKey="id"
                                listValue="ticket.country.countryName"></s:select>
                        </p>
                        <p class="yellowLg">All fields are required.</p>
                        <p>
                            <s:submit name="Submit" title="Submit"></s:submit>
                        </p>

            </table>
        </s:form>
```

**The problem:** My problem is that i am unable to display the lists inside the edit page which are actually objects inside my main object. I hope the many-to-one relation is clear to you here. Like the BusinessPurpose is a pojo mapped to a table via hibernate and the Ticket class has this object mapped as many-to-one. Same is with **Park** and **Status**. What i am trying to do is get a list of all Parks and Statuses and display it in the struts  tag and get the value to edit afterwards. But in the edit page the whole list is filled with the previous value. How can i get back a ticket object inside action class with edited/new values?

If you are unable to understand then please point out as to which part is unclear. I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question

```
Now my first question here is - can i somehow use one jsp for both save 
and edit operations ?? I can get the complete details under one ticket object.
```

You will be better off using different JSPs to perform these two tasks.

```
My problem is that i am unable to display the lists inside the edit page which 
are actually objects inside my main object.
```

Can you paste the JSP code where you are trying to access the object inside the main object.